# What is canvas URL on facebook developer account?

Tags: facebook

What is canvas URL on facebook developer account ?

How it is help-full ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Facebook application can be of the 'Canvas' type: the user will use your app within Facebook. What this means: a user goes to your canvas page (apps.facebook.com/canvasname) (this is the canvas *name*, not the canvas URL), probably via a link or bookmark within Facebook. In the top, there's still the blue Facebook bar. At the right, there's the adds and some other Facebook thingies. Way below there's still some gray Facebook links. And left (big part of the screen, hopefully) there's an iFrame.

***Here it comes.*** This iFrame is loaded from the location you specify as Canvas URL.

This is useful, even necessary  if you want your application to work as Canvas app. Note that this is not so much part of your 'developer account', it's a separate property for every app you are allowed to configure (..via your developer account, yes).

Comment: Probably most games on Facebook use this then?